# Send Bigger size json with Jboss7.1.1.Final

Tags: json, maven, http-post, jboss7.x

This is the Json format I want to send via HttpPost to the server

```
{
    "key1":"value2",             
    "key2":"value2" ,
    "key3":"value3",
    "key4":"value4",
    "key5":[
     {"key5.1.1":"value5.1.1"},
     {"key5.2.1":"value5.2.1"},
     {"key5.3.1":"value5.3.1"},
     {"key5.4.1":"value5.4.1"}
    ]   
}
```

for Smaller size Json it works fine, But problem is when jsonarrray from  key5 increases the size it throws exception .
So how do we send big JSON string using Http Post to the server?

I'm using maven and Jboss7.1.1.Final .

is there any changes I need to do in jboss configurations to accept large length JSon object ?

Also am using Webservice client to send above data in string format via HttpPost using following.

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(BASE_URL + SEND_URL + "/" + URLEncoder.encode(new Gson().toJson(input)));       
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

and it throws error only for bigger length Json String

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:115)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)

I checked following link but not got the solution

[JSON object max size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544807/json-object-max-size)

also according to http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/08/05/how-to-configure-maxjsonlength-in-asp.net-ajax-applications.aspx JSON is not limiting the size its Jboss

Comment: The json you posted does not seem to be valid.

Comment: sorry,I've modified the format.Error is still their