# ajax post json to php not receiving all data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I try to post to a php file, some data of JSON file are lost. I have a JSON-file with 1100 entries. On my server, I can only add 333 entries. On another server, I can add 1000 entries. Do I have to change my server configuration?

JSON File has 1100 entries (users)

Jquery:

```
$.post(
  'store.php',
  {json:usersJSON},
  {contentType: "application/json"}, 
  function() {
    alert(data);
  });
```

PHP:

```
$JSON = $_POST['json'];
echo json_encode($JSON);
```

on one server, this echoes 333 entries, on the other server, it echoes 1000 entries

Comment: Can you confirm that you are sending the same data to both servers?

Comment: If it's a JSON file, why are'nt you just getting it with PHP ?

Comment: Check the php.ini for [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and check PHP error log for any errors

Comment: before you can use `json_encode` need to first use `json_decode` to turn string received into array

Comment: @cwallenpoole the exact same data is sent

Comment: @adeneo I'm writing an offline webapp, so I can't use php there

Comment: @charlietfl if I don't use json_encode, only "array" gets printed, instead of the contents of the json file

Answer (score 2):

The problem was max_input_vars in my php.ini file. It was set to 1000. That means I could add a json-file with 1000 entries with one field, or 500 entries with 2 fields,...

I set max_input_vars to 5000, now I can post a json-file with 1666 entries with 3 fields.

Answer (score 0):

How large are your entries? 
It might be the server limiting your posts.
Try looking at the post_max_size directive in php.ini

Comment: entries are under 5mb, as they are locally stored in html5 localStorage. post_max_size is 8mb ...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your server's configuration. Check php.ini for the setting max_post_size and ensure that it is sufficiently large to post your data. Also check your web server settings - Apache has a LimitRequestBody directive which could be causing your problem. Finally, check your web server and PHP error logs to see if the large post is triggering any errors.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544807/json-object-max-size)

Comment: post_max_size is 8 mb. JSON File is under 8 MB, as it is stored in localStorage. I will check the LimitRequestBody directive

Comment: So I changed post_max_size to 20M, without any change. I looked for LimitRequestBody in my httpd.conf and htaccess, but didn't find it. Tried to add LimitRequestBody 0 in my httpd.conf, without change? Any other ideas?

Comment: @TomBroucke Not on top of my head, sorry. Have you looked in the link that i posted?

Comment: My json-file is like:
    {"users":[{"name":"myName","email":"myEmail","comment":"myComment"}]}

This way, I can get 333 items to my PHP-file. If i only add the name, I can send 1000 items to my PHP-file. I tried to edit max_input_vars (was 1000 originally). It changed in PHP.ini, but it's still 1000 if I check phpinfo()

Comment: max_input_vars was still commented, but still no change

Comment: Hey, I reuploaded the php-file, and now I can add more. See my own answer