# json_decode with base64 param giving error

Tags: php, json

The problem is when one of values is Base 64 encoded Image, Sometimes it echoes **JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX**. 
I believe it probably has something to do with invalid characters but I am a newbie into php and cant find any info around the web. 
This error only happens with some images, others get echoed correctly so it has nothing to do with json format, but on certain base 64 encrypt.

Json looks something like:

{"name": "testName","description":"testDescription", "image": "base64encodedImageHere"}

Here is the php reciever file:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');


if (isset($_POST['ImageData'])){

    $data = $_POST['ImageData'];

    $imageData = json_decode($data,true);

    switch(json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - Sin errores';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Excedido tamaño máximo de la pila';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Desbordamiento de buffer o los modos no coinciden';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Encontrado carácter de control no esperado';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Error de sintaxis, JSON mal formado';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Caracteres UTF-8 malformados, posiblemente están mal codificados';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Error desconocido';
        break;
    }

    foreach ($imageData as $k=>$v){
        echo $v; // etc.
    }



}else{

    echo "out of reach"
?>
```

**<<<< EDIT : >>>> For those who asked for the real json, here it is, although client output     still    doesnt show whole value, its larger than what i can paste:**

```
"name":"testName",
"description":"testDescription",
"image":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYF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\nJWLO5Tg7QeOcfSrR "
```

Comment: How is this json string being built? Are you building it by hand? If so, DON'T. use json_encode() or whatever the build system's equivalent is.

Comment: Its built on android client and done properly, since sometimes, depending on the encoded base64 image, it echoes its values properly.

Comment: Provide the exact `json` string that fails.

Comment: if it was being properly built, then it wouldn't be throwing syntax errors, unless something's mangling the string while intransit.

Comment: I cant provide the exact json since the Base 64 encrypted image is WAY TOO LARGE, maybe that's the issue? but again, some images base 64 encodes get echoed properly and doesnt throw JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX

Comment: @SuppressWarnings: so what kind of help you're expecting then? Some string is not proper json according to `json_decode`, so?

Comment: Define "way to large" in bytes/string length

Comment: Ok i edited main post, take a look please!

Comment: With your sample, that would still be valid JSON.

Comment: Yes i know, tried changing picture name because phone default pictures used different characters but it has nothing to do... im guessing it has to do with the image size and overflow string.

Comment: Maybe your json is over limit set on the server, so it is truncated to max size, similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544807/json-object-max-size P.S. though this question is really old now...